# Implementing A Wordpress Site / Custom Designed templates's HTML in Pinnacle Cart

Tags: html, wordpress, pinnacle-cart

We have built a website for a client in wordpress. Now he wants to make it using pinnacle cart , in order to sell some products. We have searched a lot but couldn't find a convincing way to make it possible. All we have found was the possibility to edit existing files but that doesn't seem to fulfill our need. Does anyone have some information or guidelines which we can follow while making this shift from normal HTML template/wordpress to pinnacle cart. Also I read something about a smarty engine being used in it. We just want to insert pinnacle cart's functionality into our design.

Comment: Must it be Pinnacle Cart? There are also many other Wordpress e-commerce plugins that you can use.

Comment: yes client specifically asked for it :( and there isn't much information anywhere about it

Comment: How deep the integration in the WP site does it have to be? That is the question.

Comment: right now the plan is to keep the website in wordpress but to redirect it to another url when customer wants to buy products but the look must remain the same as wordpress website .... we told him that we can do it using wordpress but he wants pinnacle cart :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this almost after one month, By this time you might have found a solution, But I guess this might help some one else.

Design Integration of pinnacle cart is quiet simple.

It has skin files inside the content folder which contains the themes, and admin can activate the theme from admin side.

## Steps for pinnacle cart design integration.

1. Create a new folder in skin folder.
2. Create a file `skin.xml` in it (You can copy from the other example themes)
3. In `skin.xml` `name` **should be same as your folder name**
4. Create a folder images which contains all your theme related images.
5. Create a folder styles which contains your theme related style sheets.
6. Inside styles create a file theme-default.css and put your styles in it.
7. In skin folder create another folder templates which contains the structure of the pages.
8. Refer the example themes provided by pinnacle cart and create your theme based on that.
9. What I think most important thing is - There are three places in pinnacle cart which contains desgin files :

   a. content\engine\design
   b. content\skins\skin_name
   c. content\skins\_custom\skin

All these folders contains folders and files with same name and they do the same thing. But there is a preference - So consider about the header part of the site, file corresponding to it will be `templates\layouts\zones\header.html`. 

So pinnacle cart will first look in to `content\skins\_custom\skin\templates\layouts\zones\header.html`

If the file is not there then it will look for `content\skins\skin_name\templates\layouts\zones\header.html`

If the file is not there then look for `content\engine\design\templates\layouts\zones\header.html`

If it is still not there it will throw a error.

And don't forget to activate this skin from admin side :)